# Yii2 query for posts in a space

Tags: yii2, yii2-model

I had a DB with a post table, a content table, and a space table.

A post is a type of content, and a space is a container for many posts. I want to get all posts within a space.

Post:

```
id   object_id
--------------
1    22
```

Content (object_id --> post.id):

```
id   space_id
------------------------
22   3
```

Space (id --> content.space_id):

```
id   
--------------
3
```

To get posts within a space, the controller function looked like this:

```
$posts = Post::find()
  ->joinWith('content', false)
  ->where(['{{content}}.space_id' => $space_id])
  ->all();
```

And the Post model had this function to get the content object for a post:

```
public function getContent() {
   return $this->hasOne(Content::className(), ['object_id' => 'id'])->andOnCondition(['{{content}}.object_model' => 'humhub\modules\post\models\Post']);
}
```

This worked perfectly until the database schema changed.

Now there is no longer a `space_id` column in the content table. Instead, there is a new table `contentcontainer` with a `pk` field which replaces space_id, and a `class` field (i.e. `space` class) to identify that the PK is for a space( there is also a `class` in the table).

The tables/relationships are now:

Post Table:

```
id   object_id
--------------
1    22
```

Content table (object_id --> post.id):

```
id   contentcontainer_id
------------------------
22   5
```

Contentcontainer Table (id --> content.contentcontainer_id)

```
id   pk   class
---------------
5    3    //Space
```

Space (id --> contentcontainer):

```
id   
--------------
3
```

To get all posts within a space, I now have to link 3 tables: post,content,contentcontainer.

Do I add the contentcontainer relationship to the Post model? Or modify the content model relationship in the Post model? Not sure how best to tackle without writing a big sloppy query.

I changed the controller function to this:

```
$posts = Post::find()
  ->where(['{{contentcontainer}}.pk' => $space_id])
  ->andWhere(['{{contentcontainer}}.class' => 'humhub\modules\space\models\Space'])
```

Not sure this is right and I am stuck setting up the `contentcontainer` relationship in the `Post` model.

Comment: Please, post the structure of the 3 tables

Comment: @gmc Table structures added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here''s how I solved this (results are pulled from Content model, not Post model):

```
    $content = Content::find()
     ->joinWith('contentContainer')
     ->andWhere(['{{contentcontainer}}.pk' => $space_id])
     ->andWhere(['{{contentcontainer}}.class' => 'humhub\modules\space\models\Space'])
     ->andWhere(['{{content}}.object_model' => 'humhub\modules\post\models\Post'])
     ->asArray()
     ->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a **junction table** - `contentcontainer`. There is an example in official Yii2 docs [how to decalre relation via a junction table](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#junction-table).

In your case relation in `Post` model could be something like this:

```
public function getItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Content::className(), ['id' => 'pk'])
        ->viaTable('contentcontainer', ['class' => 'space_id']);
}
```

Now you controller function will get `$posts` doing two joins insead of one.

Answer (score 0):

Create this method in the `Space` model:

```
public function getPosts() {
  return Post::find()
    ->innerJoin('contentcontainer', ['and', 
        'contentcontainer.pk = space.id',
        'contentcontainer.class = "humhub\modules\space\models\Space"'])
    ->innerJoin('content', 'content.contentcontainer_id = contentcontainer.id')
    ->innerJoin('post', 'post.object_id = content.id');
}
```